SQL query to compare column values from two tables and find mismatches
I have below query which I am using to compare some column values between two tables.
The issue is I am getting many duplicate rows of mismatch values where against a particular column value.
In my below query I am comparing column values of 'IsActive', 'Scheme' and 'routing' against the column value for 'AgentRepresentation'. Such that if the value of one of these column does not matches then I get a customized Reconciliation Status.
Also, I am checking whether this column 'AgentRepresentation' is missing in either tables or not.
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN fcubs.AgentRepresentation IS NULL THEN 'missing in fcubs'
        WHEN cepos.AgentRepresentation IS NULL THEN 'missing in cepos'
        WHEN fcubs.IsActive <> cepos.IsActive THEN 'IsActive mismatch'
        WHEN fcubs.Scheme <> cepos.Scheme THEN 'Scheme mismatch'
        WHEN fcubs.Routing <> cepos.Routing THEN 'Routing mismatch'
        ELSE 'Unknown condition'
    END AS ReconciliationStatus,
    COALESCE(fcubs.AgentRepresentation, cepos.AgentRepresentation) AS AgentRepresentation,
    fcubs.IsActive AS fcubsIsActive,
    cepos.IsActive AS ceposIsActive,
    fcubs.Scheme AS fcubsScheme,
    cepos.Scheme AS ceposScheme,
    fcubs.Routing AS fcubsRouting,
    cepos.Routing AS ceposRouting
FROM [cpe/NetworkReachability/fcubs-NetworkReachability] fcubs
Full Outer Join [cpe/NetworkReachability/cepos-NetworkReachability] cepos ON fcubs.AgentRepresentation= cepos.AgentRepresentation
WHERE fcubs.AgentRepresentation IS NULL -- Records not in fcubs
   OR cepos.AgentRepresentation IS NULL -- Records not in cepos
   OR 
   Not(fcubs.IsActive = cepos.IsActive -- Records with mismatched IsActive value
   And fcubs.Scheme = cepos.Scheme -- Records with mismatched Scheme value
   And fcubs.Routing = cepos.Routing) -- Records with mismatched Routing value
order by AgentRepresentation


Your not condition in the where clause is rendering some of the WHEN clauses useless. If the condition in not is true (im just ignoring the previous two which seems weird as well), it means only the  WHEN fcubs.IsActive <> cepos.IsActive THEN 'IsActive mismatch' will be evaluated. The case statement will return the first when that is true and ignore the rest.

I just missed that you are doing the same for the first two. You need to add some data sample and what would be the result you are expecting, because it looks like you want your ReconciliationStatus to have all the mismatch which this query will never do.

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

If you are getting duplicates, it means AgentRepresentation isn't unique in either table. Pick a join key that is unique on at least one side of the join. Since that's a full join you probably want it unique on both ends.

Thanks All for your responses
see below a sample data that i get from my original query.  The issue is that says that i have a scheme mismatch because it matches Cepos Scheme called BECS with Fcubs Scheme called FPAY and vice versa for the same AgentRepresentation number. Whereas it should have matched BECS with BECS and FPAY with FPAY and should not have found any mismatches.
ReconciliationStatus AgentRepresentation fcubsIsActive ceposIsActive fcubsScheme ceposScheme fcubsRouting ceposRouting
Scheme mismatch 083115 True True FPAY BECS D D
Scheme mismatch 083115 True True BECS FPAY D D
